# Overload operator [] to replace vector elements

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I have a **classA** which has a **vector< classB* > vObject**.

```
class ClassA{
public:
     ClassB** operator [] (int index);
private:
     vector<ClassB*> vObject
};
```

Let's Assume that vObject is filled with some classB* objects.
**What I want to do is to be able to replace classB* elements of vector like that:**

```
classA_obj[3] = classA_obj[5];
classA_obj[1] = classB_obj;
```

I tried to return a pointer of ClassB Element.
Here is my current operator implementation:

```
ClassB** ClassA::operator [](int index){
    return &vObject[index]; }
```

After that i tried the following:

```
*classA_obj[3] = *classA_obj[5]
```

The code of doing all the work with just a vector would be:

```
vector<ClassB*> vObject;
vObject.push_back(new ClassB(ARG1,ARG2));
vObject.push_back(new ClassB(ARG1,ARG2));
vObject[0] = vObject[1];
```

I'm really confused about this, I thought my code was right but it actually doesn't work. I would love if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

*The above code is just a sample of my actual code.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return a reference, you will be able to do the replacement you requested.

```
class ClassA{
public:
     ClassB*& operator [] (int index) { return vObject[index]; }
private:
     std::vector<ClassB*> vObject
};
```

However, the way you have described your usage seems to indicate you can easily change your vector to hold `ClassB` objects instead of pointers.

```
class ClassA{
public:
     ClassB& operator [] (int index) { return vObject[index]; }
private:
     std::vector<ClassB> vObject
};
```

Then instead of pushing `new ClassB` into the vector, you just push `ClassB`:

```
vObject.push_back(ClassB(ARG1,ARG2));
vObject.push_back(ClassB(ARG1,ARG2));
```

This has the advantage you not needing to explicitly visit your container to delete the pointers. Otherwise, you will need to update `ClassA` to obey the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Thanks, changing ClassB** to ClassB*& worked.
My whole application depends on ClassB with pointer and I made some code to delete the pointers in the vector, so I will stick with that but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

The ordinary `std::vector` returns a reference, so you should probably try that:

```
ClassB*& ClassA::operator [](int index)
{
     return vObject[index]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know vector returns a reference :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In the definition:
class A {
  public:
          ClassB*& operator [] (int index) { return vObject.at(index); };
  private:
          vector<ClassB*> vObject;
}
```

It's a `inline function`, nothing else to be done. However, I would check `index` just for sanity.