# Clean way to access std::vector elements in reverse order?

Tags: c++, stdvector

In Python, accessing an array's `[-1]`'th element gives the last element, and `[-2]` indexes the second to last element.

Is there a similar pretty syntax in C++ to access `std::vector` elements in reverse order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the other answers are great, and this one only complements them. Note that `std::vector::reverse_iterator` is a random access iterator. This means that you can use `operator[]` on it. In particular, the `i`th element starting from the last is `v.rbegin()[i]`. For convenience, you can define a variable `auto rv = v.rbegin();` and then use `rv[i]` to access `v[size-1-i]`.

Answer (score 8):

Revese iterators:

```
for (auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it)
{

}
```

If you want to access to the i-th element from the end:

```
*(v.rbegin() + i)
```

Or if you don't want to look like a know-it-all:

```
*(v.end() - i - 1)
```

Note that in Python you will actually use `v[-i-1]` to get to the same element, so this one uses the same number.

The trick is that vector iterators are `RandomAccessIterator` so you can add and substract indices to them.

Comment: @becko: I just had noticed and was adding it ;-).

Comment: If you needed it for a container with forward iterators, you could use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), e.g. `*(std::next(l.rbegin(), i))`.

Comment: @FredLarson: Right. But a container with forward iterators (not bidirectional) is not likely to implement `rbegin()` in the first place. This advice will probably be more useful for bidirectional iterators (not random-access).

Comment: Why not `v.rbegin()[i]`?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sure. That would be identical, but I don't like too much the looks of `()[]`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse `v.rbegin()[i]` returns an iterator, or a reference?

Comment: `auto rv=v.rbegin();` and then you can use `rv[i]` as an equivalent for `v[size-1-i]`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse `v.rbegin()[i]` seems to be the slickest way. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse iterators. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/) you have a complete example on how to do it:  .

But if you do not want to use a loop to traverse all the middle elements in the vector, you can also (along with reverse iterators) `std::advance` (it also traverses the vector as you would do it with a loop). [Link to documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/).

You can also do it in the classical way: to access the last element you would do `vector[vector.size()-1]`, to access the second element from the end `vector[vector.size()-2]`. I suppose you already knew it and were asking for a Python-look solution, but I do not know anything similar. Probably (but I am not sure) there is some way to overload the `[]` operator of the `std::vector` to allow what you are asking for. Here someone asked to do some changes in the way a vector operated: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885133/overload-operator-to-replace-vector-elements).

Hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While @rodrigo's answer addresses the question well, I'd like to add one more point regarding looping through the `std::vector`.

In Python, looping through a list (or an iterable sequence in general) goes like:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# from beginning to end
for elem in mylist:
    print(elem)

# from end to beginning
for elem in reversed(mylist):
    print(elem)
```

Since Python's for-loop is more akin to the "foreach" construct in other languages, the corresponding syntax in C++ actually uses the STL `<algorithm>`.

```
// header
#include <algorithm>

// example code
using namespace std;

vector<int> myvector {1, 2, 3, 4};

// forward
for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](int &elem){
    cout << elem << endl;
});

// reverse
for_each(myvector.rbegin(), myvector.rend(), [](int &elem){
    cout << elem << endl;
});
```

That last argument passed to `std::for_each()` is a lambda function which takes an `int&` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Boost Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) library:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (int i : v | boost::adaptors::reversed)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```